# MS Access Pivoting Query Result Rows into Columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm new to working with MS-Access reports. I have a query that returns the results of employees timesheets, grouped by both month and paycode. I'd like to make a report showing the the following

| Employee | OT Shifts Jan | Regular Shifts Jan | OT Shifts Feb | Regular Shifts Feb |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 5678 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 0 |

However my query is formatted as:

| Employee | Month | Shift | Paycode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Jan | 1 | OT |
| 1234 | Jan | 1 | Regular |
| 1234 | Feb | 2 | OT |
| 1234 | Feb | 1 | Regular |
| 5678 | Jan | 5 | OT |
| 5678 | Jan | 2 | Regular |
| 5678 | Feb | 1 | OT |
| 5678 | Feb | 0 | Regular |

Can a field on a report be conditionally told to reference a specific "Where clause" so that I can  move the fields around at will or do I need to reform my query to be able to do this?

For reference my Query code is:

```
SELECT tblAssignedEmployees.EmployeeID, Format(Date_In,"yyyy-mm") AS [Month], Count(tblShift.Date_In) AS ShiftsPerEmployee, tblAssignedEmployees.PayCode
FROM tblShift INNER JOIN tblAssignedEmployees ON tblShift.ShiftNum = tblAssignedEmployees.ShiftNum
GROUP BY tblAssignedEmployees.EmployeeID, Format(Date_In,"yyyy-mm"), tblAssignedEmployees.PayCode;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT e.EmployeeID
     , SUM(IIF(MONTH(s.Date_In) = 1 AND e.PayCode = 'OT', 1, 0) AS [OT Shifts Jan]
     , SUM(IIF(MONTH(s.Date_In) = 1 AND e.PayCode = 'Regular', 1, 0) AS [Regular Shifts Jan]
     , SUM(IIF(MONTH(s.Date_In) = 2 AND e.PayCode = 'OT', 1, 0) AS [OT Shifts Feb]
     , SUM(IIF(MONTH(s.Date_In) = 2 AND e.PayCode = 'Regular', 1, 0) AS [Regular Shifts Feb]
FROM tblShift s
INNER JOIN tblAssignedEmployees e
   ON s.ShiftNum = e.ShiftNum
GROUP BY e.EmployeeID
```

Even shorter without `IIF`, sum the True conditions but multiply by -1 since Access treats True as -1 and False as 0.

```sql
SELECT e.EmployeeID
     , SUM(MONTH(s.Date_In) = 1 AND e.PayCode = 'OT') * -1 AS [OT Shifts Jan]
     , SUM(MONTH(s.Date_In) = 1 AND e.PayCode = 'Regular') * -1 AS [Regular Shifts Jan]
     , SUM(MONTH(s.Date_In) = 2 AND e.PayCode = 'OT') * -1 AS [OT Shifts Feb]
     , SUM(MONTH(s.Date_In) = 2 AND e.PayCode = 'Regular') * -1 AS [Regular Shifts Feb]
FROM tblShift s
INNER JOIN tblAssignedEmployees e
   ON s.ShiftNum = e.ShiftNum
GROUP BY e.EmployeeID
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you! Still frustrating that Access's reporting isn't better. I thought the point was to separate the data views for the data itself.